# How to fetch Title,Thumbnail, Description information using Dailymotion API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oembed

How to embed Dailymotion content like Title, Description, Thumbnail like the FB link feature does. I have finished for youtube by using their API but now looking for Daily motion? I think it could be done by jquery/ javascript. please reply.
thnk,
dayan

Answer (score 1):

here is the url format for rest api, as you said you already did for youtube I am expecting that you know how to parse json data

https://api.dailymotion.com/video/xjfn0s?fields=title,description

Here fields indicate the list of fields you are expecting in response

http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/rest-api-reference.html#video (Check here for all possible values of fields)